# creating wordpress template

Tags: php, wordpress

I am a beginner to wordpress.

I have started working on an existing wordpress website. I need to create a new template page.

```
<div class="contain">
  <img class="main" src="assets/images/landing-promo/image.jpg"/></div>
  <img class="logo" src="assets/images/logo.jpg"/>
  <div class="hello">
    <p> hello facebook! </p>
    <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my mark-up page. I want the image and content can be uploaded from the dashboard page. 
I started creating the template with the following code.

```
<?php
/**
* Template Name: Facebook-Landing Page
*
* @package abcd123
* @since 1.0.0
*/ ?>
<div class="contain">
<img src="<?php echo get_field( 'nm_landing_logo' ); ?>" alt="landing_logo">
</div>
```

I added a new page on dashboard, called facebook-landing, using this template. 
But the page doesn't give me an option to input the image. 
[image of my dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCs6Z.png)
I have already existing pages that are working in a similar fashion. I am not sure what I am missing.

Need Help!
Thanks in advance.

Need something similar to the below image. 
[how the output should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEWF2.png)

Answer (score 2):

use `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` this code in your function.php file. that will give you feature image option for your template.